# How to convert string rows to columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this df:

| Month | TMAX | TMIN |
| --- | --- | --- |
| January | 5.3 | 2.3 |
| January | 8.5 | 2.2 |
| January | 12.5 | 2.1 |
| February | 20.3 | 1 |
| February | 15.3 | 2 |
| February | 12.3 | 3 |
| March | 13.3 | 4 |

I want to generate month columns with their respective `TMAX` values like this:

| Month | JanuaryTMAX | FebruaryTMAX | MarchTMAX | JanuaryTMIN | FebruaryTMIN | MarchTMIN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ... | 5.3 | 20.3 | 13.3 | 2.3 | 1 | 4 |
| ... | 8.5 | 15.3 | etc | 2.2 | 2 | etc |
| ... | 12.5 | 12.3 | etc | 2.1 | 3 | etc |

Would you mind to help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `groupby.cumcount` + `df.pivot`

Comment: Refer to question 10. If you feel this is wrongly closed please feel free to comment. I'll reopen if it's valid.